# Preloading on instance dependent associations not working in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

Support was added in Rails 7 for preloading on instance dependent associations. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42553

However when I upgraded my app to rails 7.0.3, running queries on such associations that need preloading still do not work.

My models:

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artist_masters, ->(artist) {
    unscope(:where).where(artist_id: artist.id)
                   .or(where(composer_id: artist.id))
                   .or(where(performer_id: artist.id))
                   .or(where(conductor_id: artist.id))
  }, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :masters, through: :artist_masters
end
 
class ArtistMaster < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :master
  belongs_to :artist, optional: true
  belongs_to :composer, class_name: 'Artist', optional: true
  belongs_to :performer, class_name: 'Artist', optional: true
  belongs_to :conductor, class_name: 'Artist', optional: true
end 

class Master < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artist_masters, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artists, through: :artist_masters
  has_many :composers, class_name: 'Artist', through: :artist_masters
  has_many :performers, class_name: 'Artist', through: :artist_masters
  has_many :conductors, class_name: 'Artist', through: :artist_masters
end
```

When I run `Artist.where.missing(:artist_masters).first` I get the error:

> ArgumentError: The association scope 'artist_masters' is instance dependent (the scope block takes an argument). Eager loading instance dependent scopes is not supported.
> from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:500:in `check_eager_loadable!'

Would someone explain why this does not work?

Answer (score 1):

The error here is a little obscure, but comes because `missing` does an `eager_load` and so is triggering the error because `preload` != `eager_load`, and as mentioned in the PR you cited *"eager loading is still unsupported"*.

If you take a look at the docs for what `preload` is vs `eager_load` you'll probably be able to work out why it was feasible to add instance dependent scopes for `preload`ing but not for `eager_load`ing, but if not just comment back and I'll explain further.

Comment: Thanks for this. If I do `Artist.joins(:artist_masters)` I get the same, so I guess that invokes an `eager_load` too.

Comment: No, but it does a join too (which is the issue).  `joins` does an inner join, `eager_load` does a left outer join.